# Add missing images based on user name's first character through paper clip in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I use paperclip gem to upload and display images.

I want to display the missing image based on the first character of the user's first name. Say if a user's name is "Foo", the missing image should display the letter F on it.

Similarly if the user's first name is "Bar", the missing image should turn out to be an image with the alphabet "B". The generic missing image works fine. I have all the 26 images with 26 individual alphabets on them. Can anyone help.
This is my code in user model.

```
 has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300", thumb: "100x100", small: "50x50", mini: "25x25>", xsmall: "15x15" },
                default_url: ":style/missingdp.jpeg",
                url: "/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                path: ":rails_root/public/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
 validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }
 validates_attachment_size :avatar, less_than: 3.megabytes
```

Comment: If they actually have an image, that should be shown instead of the missing one, right?

Comment: Google has this functionality across their product lineup FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> based on the first character of the user's first name

A more efficient way would be to use CSS with the `:before` pseudo-class, populated with the [`attr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function ([`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/L96atrpc/1/)):

```
#app/views/users/show.html.erb
<%= content_tag :div, class: "user_image", data: { name: @user.name[0] } do %>
  <%= image_tag ... if @user.avatar %>
<% end %>

#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
.user_image {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width:  50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 1px;
  background: #f00;
}

.user_image:before {
  content: attr(data-name);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  left: 40%;
  top: 30%;
}
```

This will mean you should remove the `missing` functionality from your `User` avatar:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300", thumb: "100x100", small: "50x50", mini: "25x25>", xsmall: "15x15" },
                url: "/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                path: ":rails_root/public/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
    validates_attachment :avatar, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }, size: { less_than: 3.megabytes }
end
```

---

**Interpolation**

If you wanted to make the "missing" image use the first letter of the user's name, you'd want to look at [`Paperclip Interpolation`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :avatar, default_url: ":style/missing/:missing_user.jpeg"
    validates_attachment :avatar, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }, size: { less_than: 3.megabytes }
end

#config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip.interpolates :missing_user do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.user.name[0] #-> might be attachment.instance.name[0]
end
```

---

Finally, if you want to clean up your Paperclip models, you should look at the [`default_options`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#defaults) hash (which can be overridden in model):

```
#config/application.rb
config.paperclip.defaults = {
  styles: { medium: "300x300", thumb: "100x100", small: "50x50", mini: "25x25>", xsmall: "15x15" },
  url: "/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  path: ":rails_root/public/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
}

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a method that looks to see if they have a thumbnail, and if not, chooses the appropriate missing thumbnail for them.  Spomething along these lines, you can tweak it to use the appropriate paths and method names.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def avatar_or_missing_path
    if self.avatar
      self.avatar.public_path #or whatever the method is to get the path to the avatar image
    else
      "/images/avatars/missing/#{self.first_name[0].upcase}.jpg"
    end
  end
end
```

Then in the view you can say

```
<%= image_tag user.avatar_or_missing_path %>
```

or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution to generate avatars with user initials: https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/avatarro

```
  <%= image_tag Avatarro.image(current_user.full_name), size: '24x24' %>
  <%= image_tag Avatarro.image("Igor Kasyanchuk", solid: true), size: '24x24' %>
  <%= image_tag Avatarro.image("IK"), size: '32x32' %>
  <%= raw Avatarro.svg("IK") %>
```